# angularjs GET url when loading view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to make an API call when loading one of my views.

```
controllers.controller("detailsCtrl", ["$scope", "$routeParams", "$filter", "$http", function($scope, $routeParams, $filter, $http) {

  $scope.getCurrent = function(url, id, callBack, apiCall, promise) {
    var url = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=2172797";
    var id = "&appid=d436c04d23a5a44329eb8255190a84be";
    var callBack = "&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
    var apiCall = url += id += callBack;
    var promise = $http.jsonp(apiCall);
    promise.success(function(response) {
      $scope.current = response.current;
      console.log($scope.current);
    });
  };

  $scope.cityName = $filter("filter")($scope.data.list, {
    id: $routeParams.cityId
  })[0];

}]);
```

using ng-init in the html

```
      <div ng-controller="detailsCtrl" ng-init="getCurrent()">
    <h1>{{ cityName.name }}</h1>
      <tr>
        <td>lat: {{cityName.coord.lat}}, lon: {{cityName.coord.lon}}</td>
        <td>{{}}</td>
        <td>{{}}</td>
        <td>{{}}</td>
        <td>{{}}</td>
        <td>Clouds: {{cityName.clouds.all}}</td>
        <td>{{}}</td>
        <td>{{}}</td>
      </tr>

  </div>
```

Keep getting: http://localhost:8080/api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=2172797&appid=d436c04d23a5a44329eb8255190a84be&callback=angular.callbacks._1 , any ideas why?

*note* Also making another API call in my mainview before the user navigates to the detail view. Tried ng-click when the user switches view, but it didnt make the call at all.

Comment: are you ever tried making the call at the resolve parameter on the route?

Comment: inspect the request is it fires to proper url?

Comment: tested the url in the browser, and it works.

Comment: edit: is that api support jsonp ?

Comment: can you add html code. I cannot unterstand what you want to do exactly?

Comment: Making a similar call on my mainview, without problems. Want to make another call when switching views, not getting all the data i need on the first one.

Comment: $jmachnik Yes, making another jsonp call that works.

Comment: can you share the 404 url request?

Comment: missing http:// in your hardcoded url variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using angular2 than angularjs, but believe your problem is more related to not a proper http request. I have just worked out your sample in a plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/rOZOyAcAuVcTr3njqKfH?p=preview

```
getData: function () {
          var obj = {};
          var jsonData = JSON.stringify({ obj: obj }); //For POST
          var req = {
              method: 'POST',
              url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=2172797&appid=d436c04d23a5a44329eb8255190a84be',
          };
          return this.http.post(req.url, req.data, req)
          .toPromise()
          .then(function (response) {
              return response;

          });
      }
```

There could be one obvious reason that your url is relative to your solution.

Hope this will help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please change the **url** as below and

```
var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=2172797";
```

as your not able to find the url.
In your call it will make the url to get appended from the current URL.

Comment: right, forgott the http, now i'm getting undefined in the console, only the first API call is logged in the console.

Comment: Yes marked it, was the http:// and (response) in the parameter should have been set to current.

Comment: That was not your question!